# Getting heap overflow even on deallocating memory

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the n-queen problem on leetcode. But it is giving heap overflow error on leetcode.

But on my computer when I give single input it give correct answer but on giving input multiple times it gives segmentation fault: 11 error.

And when I don't print the complete chess board. Just printing the number of different possible solution. Then also it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

//checking positioned queens
bool checkPlacedQueens(char **board, int queeni, int queenj, int n) {
    int i=queeni;
    int j=queenj;

    //checking complete row
    for(int i=queeni; i>=0; i--) {
        if(board[i][j] == 'Q')
            return false;
    }

    i=queeni;
    j=queenj-1;
    //checking left diagonal
    while(i>=0 && j>=0) {
        if(board[i--][j--] == 'Q') 
            return false;
    }

    i=queeni;
    j=queenj+1;
    //checking right diagonal
    while(i>=0 && j<=n) {
        if(board[i--][j++] == 'Q') 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

char ***placeQueens(char **board, int queenI, int n, int *returnSize, char ****result) {

    //all queens are on their correct position
    if(queenI == n) {
        (*returnSize)++;

        /*
            reallocating the memory to save all the outputs in 3D 
            array
        */
        (*result) = (char ***) realloc(*result, sizeof(char **)*(*returnSize));
        (*result)[*returnSize-1] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*n);

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            (*result)[*returnSize-1][i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                (*result)[*returnSize-1][i][j] = board[i][j];
            }
        }

        return *result;
    }//if

    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        char save = board[queenI][j];
        board[queenI][j] = 'Q';
        if(checkPlacedQueens(board, queenI-1, j, n)) {
            placeQueens(board, queenI+1, n, returnSize, result);
        }
        board[queenI][j] = save;
    }//for Loop

    return *result;
}//function

char *** solveNQueens(int n, int* returnSize) {
    char **board;
    char ***result = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **));

    board = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        board[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    placeQueens(board, 0, n, returnSize, &result);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        free(board[i]);
    free(board);

    return result;
}//char

int main(void) {
    int returnSize=0;
    int n=4;
    char ***arr;

    while(n<10) {
        arr = solveNQueens(n, &returnSize);

        for(int i=0; i<returnSize; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                    printf("%c", arr[i][j][k]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");

        for(int i=0; i<returnSize; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
               free(arr[i][j]);
            }
            free(arr[i]);
        }

        free(arr);
        arr=NULL;
        n++;
    }
}//main
```

Comment: `char ****result` - why stop, you can be [a 5 star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). The more stars the better is the code.

Comment: I don't see a single call to `free` anywhere in your code

Comment: *when I give single input* - I don't see any input taken by the program.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Inside the main n=4, then n is incrementing by 1 every time till n reach 10.

Comment: @KamilCuk, BTW awesome sarcasm :P but I have to return all possible combination thats why used 4 star variable

Comment: No. Encapsulate the data inside a structure `struct board_s { struct rows_s { int *c; } *r; };` You will loose stars... but get readability. You can use array pointers so you can have way less mallocs `char (*board)[n] = malloc(sizeof(char)*n*n);` but I know, they are  hard to use. In your code I have no idea what does `result` represent? Is it a set of strings? An array of pointers? `struct result_s { struct board_s *results; size_t resultscnt; }` would be way clearer - would represent boards with the results.

Comment: Then you can provide abstractions - write `struct board_s* boart_new(size_t n);` that would allocate new board, accessor functions `char board_get(size_t x, size_t y);` and finally a copy constructor - `struct board_s* board_copy(const struct board_s *other)` and `void result_add(struct result_s *result, const struct board_s *board)` that is pretty clear. Because for 100% you loose your sanity in those stars. And you don't check the return values of *alloc functions - are you sure you don't run out of memory? Always check the return value of mallocs, even with a simple `assert(ptr != NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

Yoor code has an out-of-bounds read illegal memory access. A live test of it is here [segfault diagnoser](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/1pHHAnwnSsOxbWnN),

The following is the diagnostic message of the out-of-bounds read.

====== Start of Stensal DTS message == (56.133) == copy start here ======

**[out-of-bounds read]** is detected by Stensal DTS.
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Reading 1 bytes from 0x80c5054 will read undefined values.
| 
| The object to-be-read (start:0x80c5050, size:4 bytes) is allocated at
|     file:/prog.c::83, 28
| 
|  0x80c5050               0x80c5053
|  +------------------------+
|  | the object  to-be-read |......
|  +------------------------+
|                            ^~~~~~~~~~
|        the read starts at 0x80c5054 that is right after the object end.
| 
| Stack trace (most recent call first) of the read.
| [1]  file:/prog.c::31, 12
| [2]  file:/prog.c::67, 12
| [3]  file:/prog.c::68, 13
| [4]  file:/prog.c::92, 5
| [5]  file:/prog.c::107, 15
| [6]  [libc-start-main]
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

======= End of Stensal DTS message =============== copy end here =========

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are not resetting the value of `returnSize` each time you re-call the `solveNQueens` function.

The following is a working code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

//checking positioned queens
bool checkPlacedQueens(char **board, int queeni, int queenj, int n) {
    int i=queeni;
    int j=queenj;

    //checking complete row
    for(int i=queeni; i>=0; i--) {
        if(board[i][j] == 'Q')
            return false;
    }

    i=queeni;
    j=queenj-1;
    //checking left diagonal
    while(i>=0 && j>=0) {
        if(board[i--][j--] == 'Q') 
            return false;
    }

    i=queeni;
    j=queenj+1;
    //checking right diagonal
    while(i>=0 && j<=n) {
        if(board[i--][j++] == 'Q') 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

char ***placeQueens(char **board, int queenI, int n, int *returnSize, char ****result) {

    //all queens are on their correct position
    if(queenI == n) {
        (*returnSize)++;

        /*
            reallocating the memory to save all the outputs in 3D 
            array
        */
        (*result) = (char ***) realloc(*result, sizeof(char **)*(*returnSize));
        (*result)[*returnSize-1] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*n);

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            (*result)[*returnSize-1][i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                (*result)[*returnSize-1][i][j] = board[i][j];
            }
        }

        return *result;
    }//if

    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        char save = board[queenI][j];
        board[queenI][j] = 'Q';
        if(checkPlacedQueens(board, queenI-1, j, n)) {
            placeQueens(board, queenI+1, n, returnSize, result);
        }
        board[queenI][j] = save;
    }//for Loop

    return *result;
}//function

char *** solveNQueens(int n, int* returnSize) {
    char **board;
    char ***result = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **));

    board = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        board[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    placeQueens(board, 0, n, returnSize, &result);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        free(board[i]);
    free(board);

    return result;
}//char

int main(void) {
    int n=4;
    char ***arr;

    while(n<10) {
        // Reset the value of returnSize
        int returnSize=0;

        arr = solveNQueens(n, &returnSize);

        for(int i=0; i<returnSize; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                    printf("%c", arr[i][j][k]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");

        for(int i=0; i<returnSize; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
               free(arr[i][j]);
            }
            free(arr[i]);
        }

        free(arr);
        arr=NULL;
        n++;
    }
}//main
```